# Deploying Webflux application Jar file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, graphql-java

I have created Graphql application with Spring Boot Webflux. I am pretty new to this. Can some one please tell me the process of deployment of same. I know about traditional tomcat deployment but i read that using that, it removes of the features.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you could deploy a spring-boot application.

- Running as a standalone JAR file
- Deploy as a WAR file into a tomcat (For Spring WebFlux application this is not [supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment.war)).

#### Deploy as a standalone JAR

To generate an executable JAR we could either use spring-boot [maven plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) or spring-boot [gradle plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) depending on your use case.

##### Spring Boot Maven Plugin

- Add following to the `pom.xml`.

```bash
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

- Run following command to generate the executable.

```bash
mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage
```

- Then run the generated JAR file with following command.

```bash
java -jar <path-to-generated-jar>/<app-name>.jar
```

##### Spring Boot Gradle Plugin

- Run following command to generate the executable.

```bash
./gradlew bootJar
```

- Then run the generated JAR file with following command.

```bash
java -jar <path-to-generated-jar>/<app-name>.jar
```